# How can I use AES-GCM encryption algorithm instead of AES algorithm (default) as a server side encryption in Alibaba Cloud OSS?

Tags: rest, api, encryption, alibaba-cloud

I want to set AES-GCM Encryption Algorithm instead of AES(default) in the REST API PutObject request. I understand the default algorithm is AES but I don't find any relevant information about changing the encryption algorithm in PutObject API request.

I use the following syntax to upload objects to Alibaba Cloud OSS:

```
PUT /ObjectName HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: ContentLength
Content-Type: ContentType
Host: BucketName.Endpoint
Date: GMT Date
Authorization: SignatureValue
```

What parameter I have to add in the above API request to have AES-GCM Encryption Algorithm in Alibaba Cloud OSS PutObject Request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KMS stands for Key Management System. KMS is not an encryption algorithm. KMS provides for creation, management and rotation of encryption keys.

Alibaba Cloud KMS provides AES-256 encryption in Galois/Counter Mode (AES-GCM). This is a standard mode of encryption provided / supported by each of the cloud vendors.

Alibaba Cloud OSS supports CMK (Customer Master Key) managed by KMS.To enable this feature set the header `x-oss-server-side-encryption:KMS` and the ID of the user KMS key `x-oss-server-side-encryption-key-id: KEY_ID`.

[What is KMS](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/28935.htm)

[Galois/Counter Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode)

[OSS Server-side encryption](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31871.htm)